# Obtaining an Elementary Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am asked to prove that

> Any elementary $n \times n$ matrix can be obtained in at least two ways either by performing an elementary row operation on $I_n$ or by performing an elementary column operation on $I_n$

Here is the definition of elementary matrix I am working with:

> An $n \times n$ elementary matrix is a matrix obtained by performing an elementary operation on $I_n$. The elementary matrix is said to be of type 1, 2, or 3 according to whether the elementary operation performed on $I_n$ is a type 1,2, or 3 operation, respectively.

In light of this definition, it seems that I am being asked to prove the definition, which is rather odd. What is the difference between the definition and what I am asked to prove? As far as proving this, I could use a hint.

Comment: In the definition of an elementary matrix, the operations used are "row operations", you are being asked to prove that performing the suggested "column" operations can also do the same.

Comment: I think they may want you to show that elementary operations are closed under composition.

Comment: @AnuragA The definition of elementary matrix doesn't use the term 'row operation' but rather elementary operation, which according to my book can refer to either a row or column operation.

Comment: @user193319 usually an elementary matrix is defined as a matrix obtained by "one" row operation performed to an identity matrix. If your book says both row and column operations are okay as elementary row operations then see if they insist only on "one" elementary operation as part of the definition. In which case Gary's comment will be useful.